# Почему не работают стили для <a>, <button> и так далее. (Для классов - работают) ASP.NET Core

Tags: css, asp.net, razor

Допустим есть html:

```css
a.green{
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
color: #fff;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 8px 16px;
margin: 20px auto;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
-o-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
}
a.green {
background-color: rgb( 43, 153, 91 );
border: 1px solid rgb( 33, 126, 74 );
}

a.green:hover {
background-color: rgb( 75, 183, 141 );
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="green">Green button</a>
```

в cshtml, но кнопка выглядит так, будто css вообще не применялся! С остальными классами все прекрасно работает. Css подключен и применяется как надо во всем кроме кнопок и ссылок!

Comment: А в инспекторе какие стили? И почему не обращаться к элементу просто по селектору класса?

Comment: Что за инспектор и где его посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

```css
a.green{
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
color: #fff;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 8px 16px;
margin: 20px auto;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
-o-transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
transition: background-color 0.1s linear;
}
a.green {
background-color: rgb( 43, 153, 91 );
border: 1px solid rgb( 33, 126, 74 );
}

a.green:hover {
background-color: rgb( 75, 183, 141 );
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="green">Green button</a>
```

Comment: Все у вас работает, значит ошибка при подключении css

Comment: Другие css классы из style.css  работают, кроме этого. Дело тут скорее в том, что я никак не могу изменить сам <a> и <button>.

Comment: Мб я что-то не до конца добавил еще. Все что я сделал чтобы добавить: кинул в wwwroot/css/ свой файл style.css, в _layout.cshtml добавил ссылку на style.css     <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" /> . Пробовал также добавлять и в свой Index.cshtml, но это тоже ничего не изменило, остальные классы работали и так, а эти не заработали)